# Laravel can't find my Service

Tags: php, laravel, service, controllers

I added the services folder in my app.  I added in composer.json the apps/services below apps/models.

Then I performed "composer dump-autoload"

Here's my Controller:

LogbookController.php

```
namespace App

use App\Services;

class LogbookController extends \BaseController {

public function index()
{
    return Response::json($this->retrieveCashLogbook('977'));

}

public function retrieveLogbookHeader($logbook){
    $log_id=$logbook->id;

    $logbook->log_shift=\App\Services\ShiftService::retrieveShift($log_id); 



    return $logbook;


}

public function retrieveCashLogbook($id){
    $logbook=Logbook::find($id);

    $logbook=$this->retrieveLogbookHeader($logbook);    
}
```

Here's my Service:

ShiftService.php

```
namespace App\Services;

//use App\Models\Shift;



class ShiftService {
    public static function retrieveShift($request){
        $shift=Shift::where("shift","=",$request)->first();
        return $shift;      
    }


}
```

It didn't matter if I put namespace App on the Service or I comment it out and replace it.  It also didn't work when I used Use App\Services or Use\App\Services or Use \App\Services\ShiftService, it still doesn't get detected.

If I added namespace App or namespace App\Controllers on my LogbookController.php, the controller isn't detected.  I'm confused what to do.

Is it the configuration?  Am I missing something?  Is there something wrong with composer and the setup?  I'm currently using PHP 5.4 but my Laravel is also an older version.

My composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/services",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: display your `composer.json`

Comment: just edited the question.  I also based it on my services folder on the app directory

Comment: Is this new project? Start with L5.6 instead. If its old project but without production environment - rewrite it!

Comment: Sorry, the company uses legacy PHP5, I don't control the upgrade of the system that's why I'm forced to use an older version of Laravel

Answer (score 0):

I solved it,

First, when I entered composer dump-autoload the next day, it worked for some reason.  I think it needed a hard reset.

Then I added this on the header of LogbookController.php:

```
use App\Services;
use App\Models;

class LogbookController extends \BaseController {
    ...

}
```

Then I added this on TransactionService.php

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Models;
use App\Services\TransactionService;


class TransactionService {
    ...
}
```

Basically, the namespace and the use statements were tricky, so I had to test and retest
using it.